# Exoplayer Recyclerview Playing Wrong Video Second Time

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

I have implemented Exoplayer in recycler view.  Let us say there are two videos, when I play the first video it plays fine.

When I play the second video after pausing the first video it plays fine.  But the time bar on the first video starts and if I pause the video from the first video view the second video is paused (able to control the second video from first video controllers)

Now if I pause the second video and play the first video it just plays the second video and am able to control this video from both videos controllers.

Please see the recycler view code below:

```
public class ChatsCursorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatsCursorAdapter.ChatsHolder> {

    public SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private Context mContext;

    public ChatsCursorAdapter(Cursor mCursor,
                              Context mContext) {
        this.mCursor = mCursor;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ChatsHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup,
                                          int i) {

        View V = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                               .inflate(R.layout.list_chat_message,
                                        viewGroup,
                                        false);

        // Build The Exoplayer
        exoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(mContext).build();

        return new ChatsHolder(V);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ChatsHolder chatsHolder,
                                 final int i) {

        String url = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("url"));

        // Play Video When Play Button Clicked
        chatsHolder.ivSharedImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {

                    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(url);

                    chatsHolder.sevSharedVideo.setPlayer(exoPlayer);

                    // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
                    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(mContext,
                                                                                        Util.getUserAgent(mContext,
                                                                                                          "Dackeree"));
                    // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
                    MediaSource videoSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(videoUri);
                    // Prepare the player with the source.

                    exoPlayer.prepare(videoSource);
                    exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Toast.makeText(mContext,
                                   "Some Error Occurred...",
                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                         .show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return mCursor.getCount();
    }

    public class ChatsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        final ImageView ivSharedImage;
        final PlayerView sevSharedVideo;

        ChatsHolder(View view) {

            super(view);

            ivSharedImage = view.findViewById(R.id.l_chat_message_iv_shared_image);
            sevSharedVideo = view.findViewById(R.id.l_chat_message_sev_shared_video);
        }
    }
}
```

The SimpleExoplyer exoplyer is public so it can be stopped/released from another activities onStop, onPause.  So that videos do not continue to play after leaving the activity.

Please help me so each video plays properly.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a [repo](https://github.com/yoobi/exoplayer-kotlin/tree/feature/rvItemPreview) in Kotlin with different functionality one of them is a `Recyclerview` of videos that I've forked from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z44CLCafepA